# Can site navigation work without <a></a> elements in my html?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

Workaround that seems to be working fine is to attach JS event listener to any element (button most likely) that you want to act as a link and within a function call   location.assign("");  to jump to that specific page.
Is there any reason I shouldn't do this ?

Comment: Search engines can't follow the links, and won't index your site.

Answer (score 2):

As Daniel said, search engines can't follow the links, and therefore they won't index your site.

That's not the only problem though, you need to use JavaScript to read if the button is clicked. What happens if the user doesn't have JavaScript enabled for their web browser? Then they have navigation looking buttons that have no functionality. They will think your website is broken.

It's okay to have buttons for navigation to some links, however the navigation bar should almost always include `<a>` anchor tags so that a user (with or without JavaScript) can navigate your site.